# Store the values in separate map on reaching a particular character in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following string

INPUT :

```
1 APPLE
2 BANANA

DOWN:

1 ORANGE
6 GRAPES
```

I want to create 2 different map and pass the values of

```
1 APPLE 
2 BANANA
```

to one map and similarly ,

```
1 ORANGE
6 GRAPES
```

for the other map . These values comes from a single array list and I want to start splitting when the character ":" is reached . Any help would be great

Comment: Well just add them to your first array until you meet `:` and then add to the second one. What's your problem ?

Comment: I'm intrigued by the intent behind the question. The input data looks like the number is a count rather than an identifier. Are you certain that a map from integer to string is the right model? It looks to me as though the fruit names are unique and you should be mapping from fruit to count. Can you provide some details behind your question? I suspect there's a better way of doing what you are asking.

Comment: How about to store them into `Map<Integer, List<String>>`?

Comment: I need the values before reaching "Down:" separately and after reaching separately in 2 different arrays @sprinter

Comment: How to do that @Nico

Comment: @Anusha I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to adapt my answer to your questions thanks to some clarifications.

```
Map<Integer, String> horizontal = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, String> vertical = new HashMap<>();
boolean horiz = true;
for(String line: al2){
  if(line.contains(":")) horiz = false;
  else if(line.trim().length() > 0) {
    String[] splitted = line.split(" ");
    if(horiz) horizontal.put(Integer.valueOf(splitted[0]), splitted[1]);
    else vertical.put(Integer.valueOf(splitted[0]), splitted[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to have all the inputs in a map . Since map doesn't allow duplicate keys but since my input has duplicate keys (Eg "1" ) I just thought of this method @Nico

Comment: @Anusha alright, but shouldn't you have them the other way around ? What does these numbers, and this "Down:" represent ?

Comment: Its a crossword game and the inputs represent the answers. I must match the answers with the clues and the only way to match is with help of integers there @Nico

Comment: Could you please explain what your code does ? @Nico

Comment: I am getting this error  "The method put(Integer, String) in the type Map<Integer,String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)"  in  Put line @Nico

Comment: Yea i understood !! Thanks but I got that above error !! @Nico

Comment: @Anusha there were a couple of typos that hopefully are fixed now.

Comment: I am getting exception error . It says exception For input string: " " @Nico

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110712/discussion-between-nico-and-anusha).

Answer (score 0):

In your output, you eliminate DOWN:  , which I assume is intended as a marker that is left out of the actual output.

Basically you create a mini statemachine that you toggle from inside your loop. With 1 boolean this is manageable like this, but with multiple values I would recommend creating a state object.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

// obviously name this after the actual purpose secondlist serves
// e.g. storeAddressDetails or whatever your usecase is
boolean putInSecondList = false;

for(String line : lines) {
    if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        // ignore whitespace
        continue;
    }
    if (line.contains(":")) {
        // skip and set passedMarker
        passedMarker = true;
        continue;
    }
    if (putInSecondList == false) {
        list1.add(line);
    } else {
        list2.add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the all the inputs to be in a map. Since my input contains duplicate keys how could I do this ? @Joeblade

Comment: @Anusha, I think you need to update your question. Write down specifically what you want and in which objects you want it. You could use json notation.

for instance:
expected output: { "1" : ["APPLE","ORANGES"], "2":["BANANA"], "6":["GRAPES"]}

any other form is fine as well ofcourse, it's just hard to guess what you're intending

Comment: @Nico has the right answer I think, though I prefer not using i<n and get(i) but that's a style thing

Comment: @Joeblade yeah you're right it's a legacy from a previous edit of the answer, I will change it to a `foreach` to make it more readable.